# Add irregular data lat/lons to Xarray Dataset for interpolation

Tags: python, python-xarray, weather, scientific-computing

So I have an Xarray dataset, `ds`, with 3 variables  in it: (example data)

```
Data variables:
    CO2      (time, data) float32 400.0 400.0 ... 400.0
    ...
```

Where the `data` dimension is a 1D array, for which I have 1D arrays of matching length containing latitude and longitude for each entry in `data`. The latitudes and longitudes are not sampled regularly. Ideally I would add the lat and lon so it showed up like this:

```
Data variables:
    CO2      (time, data, lat, lon) float32 400.0 400.0 ... 400.0
    ...
```

How can I add the lat/lon as a dimension so that I can interpolate along it using the Xarray interp function? (or is there some other, better way to interpolate this data?)

Eg: `ds_interp = ds.interp(time=dt, lat=dlat, lon=dlon, assume_sorted=False)`

Answer (score 0):

In the xarray documentation, [at the bottom of this section](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/interpolation.html#scalar-and-1-dimensional-interpolation), you can see a note saying the interpolation only works over regular grids. I will have to either grid the data and interpolate it, which I was hoping to avoid, or interpolate it as numpy arrays manually with scipy.interpolate, which supports irregular grids.